# Child element not aligned when using % values on parent

Tags: html, css

I am experiencing a problem when using % values instead of px.
For example:
http://jsfiddle.net/FXZMS/1/ works the way I want it to. Hovering over "About" gives a drop-down list. However, I would prefer to use % values so that spacing between the list items is dependent on screen size.

I tried doing it with a 10% value and this is what happens:
http://jsfiddle.net/FXZMS/2/

In the above examples all I'm changing is in the:

```
#navcontainer ul a {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 10%;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

in the first example the padding values are 56px, and in the second - 10%

Using % values, when hovering over "About" the drop-down list looks... weird. Can someone tell me why exactly this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set your menu elements to `width:25%` and do the same fo the child elements. Add `text-align: center` and it should all look nice and uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**Added CSS**

```
#navlist > li > a {
    padding-right: 4.5%;
    padding-left: 4.5%;
}

#navlist ul {
    width:100%;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/FXZMS/3/)

I didn't change the CSS you had but just added this below your CSS, you might want to replace this added part above in your CSS

Comment: I'd say this is a good enough result. However, I don't really understand why the way you did it works.

Comment: I didn't really read your CSS, I used Chrome dev-tools to find the problem, but I would just guess this: You gave `10%` padding which was too high so I just reduced it to `4.5%`, simple hit and trial value. And as the `ul` inside wasn't taking full space so I used `width:100%` for it. Remember, when you write `width: 70%`, it essentially means `0.7 * width of its parent`